# How to iterate an array-dictionary mixed structure using python3?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I have a structure:

```
[
  {
    'text':'first_layer 1',
    'children':[
                 {
                   'text':'second_layer 11',
                   'children':[
                                {
                                  'text':'third_layer 111',
                                  'children': [],
                                }
                              ],
                 },
                 {
                   'text':'second_layer 12',
                   'children':[]
                 }
              ],
  }
]
```

I am going to save this structure into database, I have a table with these columns and the expected result like this

```
-------------------------
id   parent  text
-------------------------
1    Null    first_layer 1
2    1       second_layer 11
3    1       second_layer 12
4    2       third_layer 111
```

Please teach me how to iterate through this structure.

Comment: Use recursion or a stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the idea is that you create a first in first out queue, and do a breath first search (BFS) on the object you have. Simple implementation is as following:

```
from queue import Queue

def travel_data(x):
    text_result = []
    text_queue = Queue()
    text_queue.put( (None, x) )

    id_counter = 0

    while not text_queue.empty():
        pid, obj = text_queue.get()

        for i in obj:
            text_result.append( ( id_counter, i['text'] ) )
            text_queue.put( ( pid, i['children'] ) )

        id_counter += 1

    return text_result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use recursion to accomplish this task.

> You can run the code online at http://rextester.com/ISG94336.

```
import json

def get_filtered_data(data_list, parent):
    # print(data_list, parent)
    if not data_list:
        return []

    l = []

    for d in data_list:
        parents = []
        texts = []

        if not parent:
            parents.append(None) # Python has None for Null values , JavaScript has null, C/C++ have NULL
        else:
            parents.append(parent)

        texts.append(d['text'])
        # print(zip(parents, texts))
        l = l + list(zip(parents, texts)) + get_filtered_data(d['children'], parent + 1)

    return l

# Starting point
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parent = 0

    # Input Data
    data = [
        {
        'text':'first_layer 1',
        'children':[
                     {
                       'text':'second_layer 11',
                       'children':[
                                    {
                                      'text':'third_layer 111',
                                      'children': [],
                                    }
                                  ],
                     },
                     {
                       'text':'second_layer 12',
                       'children':[]
                     }
                  ],
        }
    ]

    output_list = get_filtered_data(data, parent)
    print(output_list, '\n') # In each tuple, 1st item is parent id, 2nd one is text of current child element
    # [(None, 'first_layer 1'), (1, 'second_layer 11'), (2, 'third_layer 111'), (1, 'second_layer 12')]

    # Sorting based on parent id
    output_list2 = sorted(output_list, key=lambda tup: 0 if tup[0] is None else tup[0])
    print(output_list2, '\n')
    # [(None, 'first_layer 1'), (1, 'second_layer 11'), (1, 'second_layer 12'), (2, 'third_layer 111')]

    output_list3 = [(index + 1,) + tup for index, tup in enumerate(output_list2)]
    print(output_list3, '\n')
    # [(1, None, 'first_layer 1'), (2, 1, 'second_layer 11'), (3, 2, 'third_layer 111'), (4, 1, 'second_layer 12')]

    pretty_output = json.dumps(output_list3, indent=4)  
    print(pretty_output)
    """
    [
        [
            1,
            null,
            "first_layer 1"
        ],
        [
            2,
            1,
            "second_layer 11"
        ],
        [
            3,
            1,
            "second_layer 12"
        ],
        [
            4,
            2,
            "third_layer 111"
        ]
    ]
    """
```

#### Output

```
[(None, 'first_layer 1'), (1, 'second_layer 11'), (2, 'third_layer 111'), (1, 'second_layer 12')] 

[(None, 'first_layer 1'), (1, 'second_layer 11'), (1, 'second_layer 12'), (2, 'third_layer 111')] 

[(1, None, 'first_layer 1'), (2, 1, 'second_layer 11'), (3, 1, 'second_layer 12'), (4, 2, 'third_layer 111')] 

[
    [
        1,
        null,
        "first_layer 1"
    ],
    [
        2,
        1,
        "second_layer 11"
    ],
    [
        3,
        1,
        "second_layer 12"
    ],
    [
        4,
        2,
        "third_layer 111"
    ]
]
```